# Accessing PostgreSQL 9.6 from Spring Boot in CircleCi

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, circleci

I have a Spring Boot application that currently builds and runs tests in Heroku's CI and I'm trying to get it to work in Circle CI as well. My config file looks like this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/jdk8:0.1.1
      - image: postgres:9.6
    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: chmod +x gradlew

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: ./gradlew dependencies

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: ./gradlew test
```

I tried various ways of defining DATABASE_URL to no effect:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/jdk8:0.1.1
        environment:
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://dashman_test@localhost:5433/dashman_test
      - image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=dashman_test
        - POSTGRES_DB=dashman_test

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/jdk8:0.1.1
        environment:
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://dashman_test@localhost:5434/dashman_test
      - image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=dashman_test
        - POSTGRES_DB=dashman_test

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/jdk8:0.1.1
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: postgresql://dashman_test@localhost:5434/dashman_test
      - image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: dashman_test
          POSTGRES_DB: dashman_test


TEST_DATABASE_URL: postgresql://ubuntu@localhost/circle_test?sslmode=disable        
DATABASE_URL: postgresql://ubuntu@localhost/circle_test?sslmode=disable

DATABASE_URL: postgres://ubuntu:@127.0.0.1:5433/circle_test

DATABASE_URL: postgres://localhost:5433/dashman_test

DATABASE_URL: postgresql://ubuntu@localhost:5434/circle_test?sslmode=disable

DATABASE_URL: postgres://dashman_test:KnDnHtzneyTzps0WuYr35r9@localhost:5433/dashman_test
```

Nothing seems to work, I always end up with this error:

```
tech.dashman.dashmanserver.models.AccountTest > create FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                        Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException

tech.dashman.dashmanserver.models.UserTest > create FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                        Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException

tech.dashman.dashmanserver.DashmanserverApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                        Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException
```

What's the proper way of configuring the database? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What is your DATABASE_URL ?

Comment: @StanislavL: I added the list of every DATABASE_URL I tried. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Can't it be postgree is running in a docker container so instead of localhost you need the container IP (or name)?

Comment: @StanislavL: maybe, I don't know, but this would seem to indicate otherwise: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/postgres-config/

Comment: did you try dbl quoting `- DATABASE_URL="postgresql://dashman_test@localhost:5434/dashman_test"` as in link above?.. did you also try to add `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "some password"` as per example in docs?..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few points that should help you to address the problem.

---

**(1)** The documentation you mentioned in comments ([this one](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/postgres-config/)) is either outdated or plain misleading. This:

> The default user, port, test database for PostgreSQL 9.6 are as follows:
>   postgres://ubuntu:@127.0.0.1:5432/circle_test

... is **not true**.

The actual defaults for `postgres:9.6` are:

- username: postgres
- password: `<empty>`
- port: 5432
- database: postgres

You can reach postgres instance from your application on `127.0.0.1`.

You can find more info about defaults [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) but there is a catch about setting them (more on this in **(3)**).

---

**(2)** As far as I know [there is no way to pass usrename\password](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) in jdbc url for postgres connector, so you probably have to tell your application not only `DATABASE_URL` but also something like `DATABASE_USER` and `DATABASE_PASSWORD`.

This part is dependent on specifics of your application, but for typical spring boot application with default database settings you want to end up with the following settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
```

---

**(3)** Alternatively, if your connection settings are hardcoded you probably want to configure credentials for postgres instance.

Unfortunately, even though setting `POSTGRES_*` environment variables when running container with `docker run` works fine, setting them in `.circleci/config.yml` does not work. There are few open bug reports ([1](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41), [2](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203)) describing this or similar issue and my money is on this being a bug.

Fortunately, you still can work around this by installing `psql` and creating desired user credentials during your build (default credentials still work). Adding something like:

```
  - run: apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y postgresql
  - run:
      command: |
        psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE databasename;"
        psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -c "CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE databasename TO username;"
```

... to your `steps` should do the trick (see [full example here](https://github.com/EugeneLoy/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L16-L20)).

Using [machine executor](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/#machine-executor-overview) to run postgres manually (see last example on [this page](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/private-images/)) might be an option too, but I have not tried this one myself.

---

**(4)** I actually tried configuring this for myself and you can check out repo with [working version here](https://github.com/EugeneLoy/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa). Build [output example here](https://circleci.com/gh/EugeneLoy/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/38).

I used this [spring boot sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/6ab07f8cf00ad3da1d110f0e5a6defcf872c0883/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/) and made it use postgres, left only relevant tests, added circle ci along with other minor tweaks. It demonstrates both configuring application via env. variables and configuring postgres instance.

The most interesting parts are `.circleci/config.yml` (where credentials env. variables are defined and user\db gets created in postgres instance):

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/databasename
          DATABASE_USER: username
          DATABASE_PASSWORD: password
      - image: postgres:9.6

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y postgresql
      - run:
          command: |
            psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE databasename;"
            psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -c "CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE databasename TO username;"
- run: mvn test
```

... and `application.properties` (where credentials env. variables are used):

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=false

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=error

spring.datasource.url=${DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: Thanks. The example really helped, specially how you need to set up the properties file, which was something I was missing. I'd add it to the answer (in case the example gets deleted).

Comment: @Pablo Have no plans deleting it now, but yeah, good idea. I added properties file along with circleci config file I used in my example.